# Databinding to a reference Table WPF MVVM using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a Datagrid where I use Databinding. This Datagrid displays documents that need to be printed.I use the Entity Framework.

```
<Datagrid.Columns>
<DatagridTextColumn Header"Printed On" Binding="{Binding printed_on, Mode=OneWay,  NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, BindsDirectlyToSource=True,  IsAsync=True}" >

<DatagridTextColumn Header"State" Binding="{Binding state1.description,           Mode=OneWay,                        NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  BindsDirectlyToSource=True, IsAsync=True}" >
</Datagrid.Columns>
```

If I print a document, I set the field printed_on to the actual date, and I set the state to printed, which is an integer in an enumeration. The Field state1.description connects "to be printed" to 0, "printed" to 1 and "error" to 2.

If I update those two values, I can see the actual Date on printed on, but state1.description seems not to change in the datagrid - there is still "open", not "printed"

And I have an other Datagrid, where I show how mutch Documents are already printed and how mutch Documents have to be printed. I have a partial class, that extends the Class that is made by the Entity Framework and returns in a property a count on the documents. But if i change the state of the document, they are not updated too. The Propertys in the class look like

```
partial public class headers
public readonly property intStateOpen as integer
get 
    return from ... count
end property
```

end class

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I *can* see an error in your XAML. You say the `ID` of your object *is* updating, but the `Description` is not. Now I'm guessing that the `number` that you are `Binding` to in your example is the `ID` that you are talking about (however I don't know that because you didn't tell us).

If that is correct, then you should use the similar `Binding` for your `Description` property and remove the reference to the `state1` object:

```
<DatagridTextColumn Header"State" Binding="{Binding description, Mode=OneWay, 
    NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, IsAsync=True}">
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, if you're going to write WPF, you're going to need to use the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). This is used to notify data bound properties of changes made, either to the source or the target object, eg. the data from code behind/view model or the UI controls that that data is bound to. You need to implement this interface in your view model (or class that is set as the `DataContext` on your view (or `UserControl`)). You can follow the example given in the linked page on MSDN.

Furthermore, in WPF, you will *really* benefit from creating a view model class that contains *all* of the properties that you want to edit and/or display in the UI, which should be set as the `DataContext` for your view, or `UserControl`. I think that you may be having problems because your properties are *not* currently all accessible in one place.